# Unable to reset to a clean working directory in git

Tags: git, windows-7

I am unable to reset one particular file in my git working directory for some reason beyond my understanding!

Here goes:

I do a git reset --hard now,

```
 $ git reset --hard
 HEAD is now at 97b3164 Added clojure jars for personal tracking and also set clo
 jure classpath in jaskirat.el
```

After the hard reset:

```
 $ git status
 # On branch master
 # Changed but not updated:
 #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
 #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
 #
 #       modified:   elpa-to-submit/color-theme.el
 #
 no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I ve also tried git checkout -- elpa-to-submit/color-theme.el
But nothing seems to get me back to a "clean" unstaged working directory! :-S

Note: I have a clone of this repo from github on my linux desktop as well, and I don't see any issues like this on my desktop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your `git diff` feedback, it seems to be an EOL issue. Windows uses `\r\n`, while Linux uses `\n`. See `core.eol`, `core.safecrlf` and `core.autocrlf` settings in `git-config(1)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I set the autocrlf to false and did a checkout -- * and then set autocrlf back to true and did a checkout -- *  I am not sure what caused this in the first place but i have a clean directory now.

Comment: You must have opened `elpa-to-submit/color-theme.el` in a CRLF editor and hit "save". The editor converted all line endings to `\r\n`, Git respected the fact that you explicitly changed the line endings and didn't stomp them out. Why doesn't it "automagically" convert line endings? Because it can't differentiate between text and binary files: binary files will be corrupted when you replace `\r\n` with `\n`.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I had three day's work stashed that I couldn't apply because my working directory wasn't clean!

Answer (score 0):

It's trying its darnedest not to lose your data.  This file has been modified in your working copy.

If you actually, really don't care about the changes to that file, use

```
git checkout -- elpa-to-submit/color-theme.el
```

to restore the file to its version from HEAD (notice it says this right in the git status message).

Comment: been there done that. i put that in my question itself that i have tried git checkout. It still doesnt do the trick! Also the diff doesnt return anything, i havent made any changes that i care about.

Comment: Woops, sorry, overlooked that.  I'd consider cloning it and seeing what the status of the file is in the clone.  Also, what does `git diff` say?  Also, do you have custom clean/smudge filters?

Comment: git diff gives the whole file --- a/elpa-to-submit/color-theme.el
+++ b/elpa-to-submit/color-theme.el
@@ -1,1791 +1,1791 @@ as a diff and git diff --cached gives nothing

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by custom clean/smudge filters

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you do this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git checkout -- *
```

Comment: Nope, that din't help either. I did get a few pathspec errors saying the file(s) did not match any file known to git, but those files are part of .gitignore so they were never in the repo to begin with.